# AngularJS Filter not playing ball

Tags: angularjs

Being new to the Angular framework I started my project using the angularSeed download. I have services and directives working fine but today I needed a filter and I just can't seem to get one working.

I have set up  [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/method7/33gmv6xk/#base)  with a basic example of my setup and commented out my filter call because its causing errors. I simply  want to filter out qty = 0, your experience would be much appreciated; :-)

```
<div ng:app="myApp">
 <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <!-- div ng-repeat="item in items  | {filter : notZero}" -->
  <div ng-repeat="item in items" >
   <strong>{{item.title}}</strong> {{item.qty}}
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

and the JS

```
angular.module('myApp', [
 'myApp.controllers',
 'myApp.filters'
]);

angular.module('myApp.filters', [])
  .filter('notZero', function() {
   return function( items, condition) {
   console.log( items, condition);
  };
 });

angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
 .controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.items = [  
    {  
      "title":"40cm",
      "qty":3
   },
   {  
      "title":"55cm",
      "qty":2
  },
  {  
      "title":"60cm",
      "qty":0
  },
  {  
     "title":"70cm",
     "qty":4
  }
];
```

});

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**:

define an app filter this way:

```
myApp.filter('qtyNotZero', function() {
  return function(items) {
    var afterFilter = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
          if(item[i].qty != 0)
              afterFilter.push(item[i]);
      }      
    return afterFilter;
  };
});
```

and then simply:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items  | filter: qtyNotZero>
```

---

The filter should be applied for the qty:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | filter: {qty: '!0'}">
```

Or, if you have a more complicated filter, this way you can filter with your own logic:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" | filter: PositiveQty>
...
$scope.PositiveQty = function(item) {
    return item.qty > 0;
}
```

Anyway, you could also use:

```
<div ng-show="item.qty">
    <strong>{{item.title}}</strong> {{item.qty}}
</div>
```

Comment: this does in fact work but my problem is with the filter      '.filter('notZero', function()'
I want to use a filter within the above example not bypass the problem - I have been doing that all week :-P

Comment: yes this does solve my problem {qty: '!0'} thank you BUT say I want to apply a app.filter method and write a filter. the fiddle now shows the JS errors [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/method7/33gmv6xk/)

Comment: @method7 Please open a different question for this matter.

Comment: filter : {option_qty : '!0'} filters 10 and 20 and anything with a 0... how can i make this filter just zreo (0) value

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ways to approach this:

- You can have `ng-repeat` modified as: `ng-repeat="item in
  items|filter:{qty: '!0'}"`
- Write your own filter which checks the `qty` is greater than zero.
- Use `ng-if`: `<div ng-if="item.qty > 0"><strong>{{item.title}}</strong> {{item.qty}}</div>`

Comment: hey Pam this does solve the issue (as above) I have with the repeater but not the one I have trying to get the app.filters bit working like services and directives  see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/method7/33gmv6xk/)